# How to change a file type and run that file using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, command-prompt, file-type

I am currently trying to use a file downloaded from the internet but run it as a different file. I have written:

```
cscript.exe /NoLogo "https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr" >"numbers.txt""
```

but I actually wanted to run filetorun.vbr as a .vbs file. For security reasons, I could not upload the .vbs version so I had to settle for .vbr.

What can I do to run the vbr file as a vbs file?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

According to this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx

Cscript.exe only support *.vbs and *.js

> Cscript.exe is a command-line version of the Windows Script Host that
>   provides command-line options for setting script properties. With
>   Cscript.exe, you can run scripts by typing the name of a script file
>   at the command prompt. Like Microsoft Internet Explorer, Windows
>   Script Host serves as a controller of Windows Script compliant
>   scripting engines, but Windows Script Host has very low memory
>   requirements. Windows Script Host is ideal for both interactive and
>   non-interactive scripting needs, such as logon scripting and
>   administrative scripting. Windows Script Host supports scripts written
>   in VBScript or JScript. When you start a script from your desktop or
>   from the command prompt, the script host reads and passes the
>   specified script file contents to the registered script engine. The
>   script engine uses file extensions (**that is, .vbs for VBScript and .js
>   for JScript**) to identify the script. As a result, you do not need to
>   know the exact programmatic identifier (that is, the ProgID) of the
>   script engine. The script host maintains a mapping of script
>   extensions to programmatic identifiers, and uses the Windows XP
>   association model to start the appropriate engine for a given script.
>   For more information about Windows Script Host, see Windows Script
>   Host For more information about CScript.exe, see To run scripts using
>   the command-line-based script host (cscript.exe)

Comment: yeah I know my code is wrong, which is why I said my intention is to run the vbr as a vbs file. The code written in the vbr file is suitable for conversion to vbs and I know since I'm the person who wrote it. I was hoping there can be a way to run the vbr file as a vbs file. Thanks though! :)

Comment: @bellere If you've security restriction on uploading file with *.vbs extension, maybe you can do a rename before running the script?

Comment: The main reason that *.vbr wont work is Cscript internally uses the file extension to differentiate between vbscript and jscript. It's hardcoded...

Comment: Yeah I tried to rename it, but the site denied the rename because it saw the .vbs extension.

Comment: Is there any command-line version of the Windows Script Host engines that can run vbr?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the scripting language with the `/E` option:

```
cscript.exe /E:VBS myfile.vbr
```

Comment: I tried:    cscript.exe /NoLogo"https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr" >"numbers.txt"".                                                                       However it showed the error:                                                         CScript Error: Loading script "C:\Users\Bel\Desktop\https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr" failed (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. ). Note that the problem is that it goes to C:\Users\Bel\Desktop\ when I just want to access the site directly. Is there a solution?

Comment: oops I meant I tried: cscript.exe /E:VBS https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr>"numbers.txt"". The problem still exists.

Comment: Use a double slash in E option: `cscript.exe //E:VBS myfile.vbr`

Comment: @bellere: It doesn't work because you're trying to run a script from an URL. You need to download the script to your computer first. See [my andwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23827526/113116).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will run vbr. It is your URL that is wrong. You have two percent signs. But in script just use a space, as we aren't a browser and don't have to follow their silly rules.

```
wscript //e:vbs "C:\Users\A User\Desktop\CreateTextFile.vbr"
```

Comment: so I tried                                                                wscript.exe //e:vbs "https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/gms.vbr" >"numbers.txt". But there was an error saying                    CScript Error: Loading script "C:\Users\Bel\Desktop\somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr"; failed (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. ). Note that the problem is that it goes to C:\Users\Bel\Desktop\ when I just want to access the site directly. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What are you trying to do. This is a programmers web site. You are expected to be able to use Windows. I told you what was wrong so you did the same wrong thing???????. You can't run scripts over the internet. It takes a file path. Is that link a UNC or a URL (a web address). If a UNC (a file path) then servers are prepended with \\

Answer (score 0):

Windows Script Host cannot run scripts directly from Internet (from HTTP/HTTPS links). You need to download the script to your computer first.

For example, using VBScript:

```
strURL = "https://somesite.net/personal/me/Shared%%20Documents/filetorun.vbr"
strFileName = "C:\filetorun.vbs" ' Note the VBS extension - you can rename files when downloading

DownloadFile strURL, strFileName

Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cscript """ + strFileName + """"


Sub DownloadFile(URL, LocalFileName)
  Dim oHttp : Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  Dim oStream : Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  oHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
  oHttp.Send

  oStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary 
  oStream.Open
  oStream.Write oHttp.responseBody
  oStream.SaveToFile LocalFileName, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
End Sub
```